# Sorting and Displaying Entries from an Array in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I wrote this program that sorts number grades into letter grades:

```
        int [] a = new int[20];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 20 Grades to be Counted:");

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] >= 90)
        aCount++;

        else if(a[i] < 90 && a[i] >=80)
        bCount++;

        else if (a[i] < 80 && a[i] >= 70)
        cCount++;

        else if (a[i] < 70 && a[i] >=65)
        dCount++;

        else
        fCount++;
    }


    System.out.println("Number of A's: " + aCount);
    System.out.println("Number of B's: " + bCount);
    System.out.println("Number of C's: " + cCount);
    System.out.println("Number of D's: " + dCount);
    System.out.println("Number of FAILURES: " + fCount);
}
```

}

What I want to do is take the inputed grades, and display the actual number grades within their respective letter. Sort of like this:

A's:
100
95
90

B's:
88
85

C's:
79
77

... and so on. How can this be done?

Comment: see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135493/informing-new-users-of-how-to-accept-answers

Answer (score -1):

You can use Sets to store the individual grades. And to store the grades in sorted order you can use a `TreeSet<Integer>`. And then iterate over the sets.

```
    int [] a = new int[20];
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 20 Grades to be Counted:");

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        a[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }


    TreeSet<Integer> setA = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    TreeSet<Integer> setB = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    TreeSet<Integer> setC = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    TreeSet<Integer> setD = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    TreeSet<Integer> setF = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] >= 90){
            aCount++;
            setA.add(a[i]);
        }

        else if(a[i] < 90 && a[i] >=80){
            bCount++;
            setB.add(a[i]);
        }

        else if (a[i] < 80 && a[i] >= 70){
            cCount++;
            setC.add(a[i]);
        }

        else if (a[i] < 70 && a[i] >=65){
            dCount++;
            setD.add(a[i]);
        }

        else{
            fCount++;
            setF.add(a[i]);
        }
    }


    System.out.println("Number of A's: " + aCount);
    System.out.print("A's: ");
    for(Integer x : setA){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Number of B's: " + bCount);
    System.out.print("A's: ");
    for(Integer x : setA){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Number of C's: " + cCount);
    System.out.print("B's: ");
    for(Integer x : setB){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Number of D's: " + dCount);
    System.out.print("C's: ");
    for(Integer x : setC){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Number of FAILURES: " + fCount)
    System.out.print("D's: ");
    for(Integer x : setD){
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

EDIT: In case of duplicates, you can use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to store the values and then sort the ArrayList using [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) before displaying the results.

Comment: I guess this won´t work, as it will eliminate repeated results. Instead of a Set, he would probably need to use a List

Comment: I have edited the post for the case when there will be duplicates.